# В MASM не работают опкоды cmovg, cmovl

Tags: ассемблер, masm

Я пытаюсь учить ассемблер по книге Modern x86 assembly language programming. В книге есть пример типа:

```
 .model flat,c
 .code
 ; extern "C" int 
 SignedMinA_(int a, int b, int c);
;
; Description: Determines minimum of three signed integers
; using conditional jumps.
;
; Returns min(a, b, c)
SignedMinA_ proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    mov eax,[ebp+8] ;eax = 'a'
    mov ecx,[ebp+12] ;ecx = 'b'
    ; Determine min(a, b)
    cmp eax,ecx
    jle @F
    mov eax,ecx ;eax = min(a, b)
    ; Determine min(a, b, c)
    @@: mov ecx,[ebp+16] ;ecx = 'c'
    cmp eax,ecx
    jle @F
    mov eax,ecx ;eax = min(a, b, c)
    @@: pop ebp
    ret
SignedMinA_ endp
; extern "C" int SignedMaxA_(int a, int b, int c);
;
; Description: Determines maximum of three signed integers
; using conditional jumps.
;
; Returns: max(a, b, c)
SignedMaxA_ proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    mov eax,[ebp+8] ;eax = 'a'
    mov ecx,[ebp+12] ;ecx = 'b'
    cmp eax,ecx
    jge @F
    mov eax,ecx ;eax = max(a, b)
    @@: mov ecx,[ebp+16] ;ecx = 'c'
    cmp eax,ecx
    jge @F
    mov eax,ecx ;eax = max(a, b, c)
    @@: pop ebp
    ret
SignedMaxA_ endp
; extern "C" int 
SignedMinB_(int a, int b, int c);
;
; Description: Determines minimum of three signed integers
; using conditional moves.
;
; Returns min(a, b, c)
SignedMinB_ proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    mov eax,[ebp+8] ;eax = 'a'
    mov ecx,[ebp+12] ;ecx = 'b'
    ; Determine smallest value using the CMOVG instruction
   cmp eax,ecx
   cmovg eax,ecx ;eax = min(a, b)
   mov ecx,[ebp+16] ;ecx = 'c'
   cmp eax,ecx
   cmovg eax,ecx ;eax = min(a, b, c)
   pop ebp
   ret
SignedMinB_ endp
    end
```

Так вот. В Ассемблере MASM не работает инструкция cmovg, и подобные ей, притом в учебнике всё выполняется именно в нем. Может ли быть это связано с платформой? Как работает MASM? Он просто прокладывает дорогу до Ассемблера системы? У меня WindowsXP. Есть ли альтернативы? MASM скачан с сайта masm32.com

Comment: Что значит "не работают"? Не компилируется вообще, ошибка, или код не делает то что вы ожидаете?

Comment: Output компилятора отмечает строчку с этой командой и не выполняет код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по [этому обсуждению](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=403.0;wap2), в начало файла после импортов (если они есть) нужно добавить

```
.686p
.mmx
.xmm
```

Comment: Нет. Дело не в этом... В masm нужно только .486

Comment: Но я попробую. Спасибо.

Comment: @АннаДостоевская, тогда попробуйте без .686p, но с mmx и xmm.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло... Правда я не могу понять что это за флаги... Они подключают модули?  В книге о них ни слова, а в инете нашлось только .486...

Comment: Прости, ссылка не сразу увиделась! И ещё раз больщое спасибо. Первый раз задаю вопросы на таких форумах. Спасибо.

Comment: @АннаДостоевская, это указание что используется расширенный набор инструкций процессора. К примеру, когда-то были процессоры Intel Pentium 166 и Intel Pentium 166 MMX (точность названий не гарантирую). Тот что без MMX не поддерживал [MMX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMX) инструкции.

Comment: а как импортировать FPU? У меня асм жалуется на fsubp, fmulp, не знаешь что надо написать чтобы он и его подключил? Помоги пожалуйста, а то я нигде(включая и иностранные сервисы) не могу найти.

Comment: @АннаДостоевская, с `.486` должно работать.

Comment: В начале так и ставила... Но не работало... Потом поставила .686р по  твоему совету. Или мне просто добавить после  686р + 486? Попробую. Если есть другой вариант, скажи.

Comment: В начале так и ставила... Но не работало... Потом поставила .686р по  твоему совету. Или мне просто добавить после  686р + 486? Попробую. Если есть другой вариант, скажи.

Comment: 486 - это модель процессора (точнее часть номера модели [Intel 80486](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/80486)). Директива `.486` позволяет использовать все инструкции, доступные для этой модели процессора. `.686p` - это директива, которая позволяет использовать все современные инструкции архитектуры [x86](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) кроме расширений (тех же mmx, xmm).

Comment: Я и его тоже подключила, но тем не менее, он продолжает жаловаться на инструкции fsubp, fmulp... Самое главное остальные инструкции от FPU нормально работают.

Comment: @АннаДостоевская, должно быть одно - либо `.486`, либо `.686p`. Не видя вашего кода трудно сказать в чем проблема.  И желательно еще текст ошибки.

Comment: https://vk.com/herrainsstudio вот. Пожалуйста, свяжись со мной через ВК. Там будет проще отослать тебе все! Спасибо

Comment: @АннаДостоевская, я не даю персональных консультаций. Задайте отдельный вопрос здесь.

Comment: Эмм... Вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1031161/masm-не-работают-опкоды-типа-fsubp-fmulp