# MASM не работают опкоды типа fsubp, fmulp

Tags: ассемблер, windows-xp, masm

[image: код из учебника]

[image: мой код]

[image: output компилятора]

Проблема:
MASM не работают опкоды типа fsubp, fmulp
В output-e можно увидеть что он указывает именно на эти строчки. Это лишь часть программы, слово end есть в конце.

Comment: Текстовая информация в вопросе должна быть представлена в виде текста, а не скриншотов. Для форматирования кода его нужно выделить и нажать кнопку `{}` в редакторе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Не нужно использовать обе директивы `.686p` и `.486` одновременно. Оставьте только одну.
2. Текст ошибки нужно читать. Там написано, что у инструкций неправильные операнды (фактически их нет). См тут например: [Система команд сопроцессора](https://prog-cpp.ru/asm-coprocessor-command/).

   - `FSUBP ST(i), ST(0)` - означает, что первым операндом должен быть один из регистров `ST(0)` - `ST(7)`, вторым - `ST(0)`.
   - `FMULP ST(i), ST(0)` - аналогично

Судя по логике кода, должно быть `FSUBP ST(1), ST(0)` и `FMULP ST(1), ST(0)`.
Теоретически MASM должен принимать и вариант без операндов, но похоже вам "повезло", и у вас версия которая не принимает такой вариант.

MASM под рукой нет, но JWASM такой код ассемблирует:

```
.486
.model flat, c

.code
start:
fsubp st(1), st(0)
fmulp st(1), st(0)
end start
```

Comment: Здравствуй. Спасибо. Да я уже довольно давно нашла ошибку ... От её тупости я просто ахренела... Прошу прощения за этот вопрос у всех кто его увидит  ... Не думала что в учебнике есть ошибки... Ещё раз простите. Спасибо что ответил @insolor